# Why does free() only set the 8 first bytes to zero?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I've a question about free() behavior.

Juste a simple code which use malloc and strcpy a char*. So, all is set on the HEAP :

```
(gdb) x/100b 0x602010
0x602010:   66  111 110 106 111 117 114 32
0x602018:   116 111 117 116 32  108 101 32
0x602020:   109 111 110 100 101 0   0   0
0x602028:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x602030:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x602038:   33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

When I free the chunk with free(), the result is :

```
(gdb) x/100b 0x602010
0x602010:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x602018:   116 111 117 116 32  108 101 32
0x602020:   109 111 110 100 101 0   0   0
0x602028:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x602030:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x602038:   33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Simple code to prove that :

```c
int main ()
{
    const char * str = "Bonjour tout le monde";

    char *ptr = (char *) malloc (strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(ptr, str);

    printf("*ptr : %s\n\n", ptr);

    free(ptr);

    printf ("After free ptr = %p\n", ptr);
    printf ("Content ptr    : %s\n", ptr);
    printf ("Content ptr+8 : %s\n", ptr+8);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Output :

```
*ptr : Bonjour tout le monde

After free ptr = 0x13c7010
Content ptr    : 
Content ptr+8 : tout le monde
```

Does someone has the answer?

Comment: In a typical heap implementation, the free() function adds the block back to a list of free blocks.  So odds are that you are seeing the side-effects of that operation, with the zeros written to indicate there is no previous and next pointer yet to other free blocks.  Look in your CRT source code.

Comment: And there are plenty of times that you might see other effects in just-freed memory.  For example if using a debug runtime, most of the memory block will quite possibly be filled with some value that is more likely to crash your program if you mistakenly use it - and that value won't be zero. Basically, once you free the block it's not yours. What the runtime does with it is up to the runtime.

Answer (score 6):

`free()` is not required to clear memory, and really it shouldn't because doing so would take time and overwrite cached data for no universally required benefit.

It's certainly allowed to use the internal space for its own purposes. What you are seeing may be just a side effect of the allocator keeping track of free memory.

Answer (score 4):

A better question would be; why do you think it should do anything else?  Where did you find documentation regarding the mandated implementation of `free`?  It doesn't exist, so it makes no sense to ask such a question.

`free` simply has to mark that memory as freed.  What happens to that block of memory after calling `free` is unspecified.

---

As an aside, this is UB:

```
printf ("Content ptr    : %s\n", ptr);
printf ("Content ptr+8 : %s\n", ptr+8);
```

Comment: I never think that argument would change after the free() call, it'll be the same before and after free(), it's just an information for me :).
Thanks for your answer, but what do you mean by "implementation defined" ?

Comment: It means that every compiler/runtime is free to do whatever it likes. It may zero-set the freed memory (with waste of computing cycles) or it may not. The only important thing is that the runtime/O.S. now knows that part of memory is free to use again.

Comment: @j0llyJumper: Ok, I was going off of this line: `printf ("After free ptr = %p\n", ptr);`

Comment: Small correction: what happens to that block of memory after calling `free` is **not** "implementation defined". The phrase "implementation defined" has a very specific (and natural) meaning: the implementation is required to define (as part of its documentation) what happens. On the other hand, attempting to access an object after its lifetime has ended has *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @r: I realize what "implementation defined" means.  How is it not implementation defined exactly?  nothing in the C spec states what the state of that memory should be after `free` is called, only that the memory is marked as free once more.  How the memory is marked as free and how it is handled is up to *the implementation*.  Perhaps we're just misunderstanding one another.  Also, there is no UB here as `ptr` is never dereferenced after the call to `free`, but you know that.

Comment: @EdS.: If something is "implementation defined", you can expect compiler/library documentation to say exactly how it's handled.  Man pages don't typically say anything about the contents of freed memory.  And `printf("... %s", ptr);` isn't UB?

Comment: @aschepler: Yes, I'm sorry; I missed the `%s`.  That is certainly UB. However, you will not necessarily find an exact definition for all implementation defined aspects of a spec.  It simply means that it is up to the implementation as to how it is handled.  There is no mandate that the implementation specify that to *you* (us).  Perhaps I should have simply said that it is "unspecified".

Comment: @EdS.: Usually the phrase "implementation defined" has the technical meaning it is given in the C and C++ Standards: the Standards specify certain behaviors are implementation-defined, meaning the Standard does require the implementation specify a behavior to us.  Writing to freed memory is not one of these things.

Comment: @aschepler: I've never heard that last part, do you have a reference?  Anyway, like I said; I should have said it is unspecified by the standard.

Comment: @EdS.: C99 3.4.1 "implementation-defined behavior" - "unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made", 3.4.3 "undefined behavior" - "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which this International Standard imposes no requirements", 3.4.4 "unspecified behavior" - "behavior where this International Standard provides two or more possibilities and imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance". The state of the freed memory block isn't unspecified; it's undefined, plain and simple.