# fread skips first 8 characters

Tags: c, file-io, fread

I am trying to read in a file, hello.ms containing the following:

```
Hello World!
```

Using this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int store_file(char* file_dir, char** buffer)
{
    FILE* file;
    long lSize;
    size_t result;
    char* tempBuffer;

    file = fopen(file_dir, "r");
    if (file==NULL)
    {
        fputs("File error.", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    tempBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (tempBuffer == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Memory error.", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }

    result = fread(tempBuffer, 1, lSize, file);
    if (result != lSize)
    {
        fputs("Reading error.", stderr);
        exit(3);
    }

    *buffer = tempBuffer;
    free(tempBuffer);
    fclose(file);

    return lSize;
}

void fsa_cycle(char* file_dir)
{
    char* buffer;
    int bufferSize = store_file(file_dir, &buffer);

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\nSyntax: %s <file-name>\n\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fsa_cycle(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles perfectly fine. No warnings or errors. But it only outputs `rld!`

When I add 8 spaces to the hello.ms file, it then reads `Hello World!`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I tried writing fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR) instead of rewind but that didn't work either. I couldn't find any help on Google that didn't suggest that the programmer forgot to use fseek to get to the beginning. Any assistance would be awesome!

Comment: doesn't fopen when opened with "r" guarantee that the position indicator will be at the start of the file?  Have you tried just fopening the file and reading it without any seeking?

Comment: Why are you seeking?  Just use Fgets: fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Comment: @ScottyBauer Well the reason you seek is to find the file size I believe. To set the lSize variable no? I am no expert though.

Comment: No, i understand that.  But why do that?  Each call to Fread is going to take a lot of time compared to fgets.  There's no advantage to reading character by character, and fgets is safe (if your buffer is large enough).

Comment: But fread is only called once as opposed to fgets which is line by line? I'm not sure I understand. I do recognize, however, that fgets is a more accepted method. But if I can find a solution to this problem I think I will clear up a problem other users are having as well.

Comment: for text streams ftell() may not be the right function to use. I looked at your code more closely, you use fseek to get to the end then ftell(), then I would fseek back to the beginning with SEEK_SET

Comment: @ScottyBauer I am using rewind to do that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `free` to release `tempBuffer` memory, but that memory block is in fact assigned to `buffer`.

[`free`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916678/why-does-free-only-set-the-8-first-bytes-to-zero) might work different with different compilers, but mine works as yours, just remove `free(tempBuffer);`

Comment: Documentation that I read said that it was important to free tempBuffer after malloc after I was done with it. If not there, where would the appropriate place to free that memory be? Or do I not need to worry about it because I'm assigning buffer to it?

Comment: You're not "done with it" until after you write it to `stdout` in `fsa_cycle`.

Comment: `*buffer = tempBuffer;` means both pointers point to the same memory block. use `free(...)` when you no longer need that memory block, this is, when you don't need `tempBuffer` and `buffer`

Answer (score 2):

You are freeing the buffer too early.
You should free the memory after you use the buffer. The line:

```
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran it in gdb and things go wrong after the free(tempBuffer);

(gdb) 
31      if (result != lSize)

(gdb) print tmpBuffer

No symbol "tmpBuffer" in current context.

(gdb) print tempBuffer

$3 = 0x602250 "Hello World!\n"

(gdb) n

37      *buffer = tempBuffer;

(gdb)

38      free(tempBuffer);

(gdb) print buffer

$4 = (char **) 0x7fffffffe180

(gdb) print *buffer

$5 = 0x602250 "Hello World!\n"

(gdb) n

39      fclose(file);

(gdb)

41      return lSize;

(gdb) print *buffer

$6 = 0x602250 ""

(gdb) print tempBuffer

$7 = 0x602250 ""

Answer (score 0):

try to use in this way

```
    char *buff;
buff = calloc(sizeOfFileInBytes + 1, sizeof(char));//replace sizeOfFileInBytes with file size (use stat to get file size)
if (!buff) {
    printf("error : %s", strerror(errno));
    fclose(f);
}
fread(buff, sizeOfFileInBytes, 1, f);

fclose(f);
printf("%s\n", (char *) buff);//lets echo what we get from fread;
free(buff);//lets return memory to heap
```